# How to mock a method whose parameter is a new instance in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest, scalamock

I have a method in a class:

```
def delete(Token, Client, Scope): Future[Int]
```

and this method is called elsewhere in another class inside another method as:

```
acr.delete(Token(token), client, scope)
```

where `token` is a `String` and `client` and `scope` are types of `Client` and `Scope` respectively:

```
case class Client(client:   String) extends AnyVal
case class Scope(scope:     String) extends AnyVal
```

When I try to mock the `delete` method in my test, I do it as :

```
when(mockService
            .delete(
              token      = any[Token],
              service    = any[Client],
              scope      = any[Scope]
            )
        ).thenReturn(1.toFut)
```

which yields a Matching Exception which causes a Null Pointer Exception:

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception. Cannot evaluate repositories.common.Service$MockitoMock$1804616202.toString()
```

`mockService` is a `mock[Service]`. I have another method mocked, belonging to `Service` and that mock does not throw any errors

When I debug it line-by-line, the code fails on the `token      = any[Token]` line. I'm not sure how else I can use `Matchers` and construct a mock.

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Why do you extend a case class with `AnyVal`?

Comment: The reason I have extends AnyVal is to use them as wrapper classes because three Strings in a row can be confusion and increases room for error.

Sorry, I explained it in the answer

Comment: I am not sure I understand which room for error, but I'm sure there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your code looks the same as:

```
case class Token(client:   String) extends AnyVal
case class Client(client:   String) extends AnyVal
case class Scope(scope:     String) extends AnyVal

class Service(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext) {
  def delete(token: Token, client: Client, scope: Scope): Future[Int] = {
    Future(1)
  }
}
```

and for this code, you can create `Token` as `Token[any[String]]`

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar.mock
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.global
val mockService: Service = mock[Service]
when(
  mockService.delete(
    token      = Token(any[String]),
    client    = Client(any[String]),
    scope      = Scope(any[String])
  )
).thenReturn(Future(2))
```

this code works and doesn't throw NPE.

I have assumption: your code throws NPE because case classes extends `AnyVal`.
Let's look at `AnyVal` source code:

```
abstract class AnyVal extends Any {
  def getClass(): Class[_ <: AnyVal] = null
}
```

it has `getClass` which returns `null` - that sounds not null-safety. If you will remove `extends AnyVal` from your case classes, your code will work. Probably `any` matcher call `getClass` inside itself, so it's a usual things for testing libraries.

Comment: I understand the explanation more clearly now! Many thanks for this! The reason I have `extends AnyVal` is to use them as wrapper classes because three `String`s in a row can be confusion and increases room for error. I wish I could eliminated `AnyVal` - I bet it probably would make my life easier!